# Is there a better way to determine if a string can be an integer other than try/catch?

Tags: c#, validation

I needed a **function** that simply checks **if a string can be converted to a valid integer** (for form validation).

After searching around, I ended up using a function I had from 2002 which works using C#1 (below).

However, it just seems to me that although the code below works, **it is a misuse of try/catch** to use it not to catch an error but to determine a value.

**Is there a better way to do this in C#3?**

```
public static bool IsAValidInteger(string strWholeNumber)
{
    try
    {
        int wholeNumber = Convert.ToInt32(strWholeNumber);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

## Answer:

John's answer below helped me build the function I was after without the try/catch. In this case, a blank textbox is also considered a valid "whole number" in my form:

```
public static bool IsAValidWholeNumber(string questionalWholeNumber)
{
    int result;

    if (questionalWholeNumber.Trim() == "" || int.TryParse(questionalWholeNumber, out result))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
if (int.TryParse(string, out result))
{
    // use result here
}
```

Comment: And long.TryParse for 64-bit values too.

Answer (score 11):

This probably won't be much faster, but at least it looks cleaner (no exception handling):

```
 public static bool IsAValidInteger(string strWholeNumber)
 {
     int wholeNumber;
     return int.TryParse(strWholeNumber, out wholeNumber);
 }
```

Comment: Actually it will be significantly faster for situations where you repeatedly get invalid strings.

Comment: I suspected that. I was just about to test it ... but there no point now because since Jon Skeet has confirmed it :-)

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for [Int32.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx).

```
public void Foo(String input)
{
    Int32 number;
    if (Int32.TryParse(input, out number))
    {
        DoStuff(number);
    }
    else
    {
        HandleInvalidInput(input);
    }
}
```

In your specific case I would use the following.

```
public static Boolean IsValidInt32(String input)
{
    Int32 number;
    return Int32.TryParse(input, out number);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Int32.TryParse

Answer (score -4):

The try/catch approach is a valid solution because for many types there are not TryParse methods implemented. So you revert to the basically one option left.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (ie. string to integer).

Comment: It does. It tells the author there is no better option.

Comment: Actually for integers there is a better option as others mentioned.